# How to tell which disk files a KVM guest is using?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization

I have an Ubuntu guest running under KVM that has several partitions of the same size, each using different virtio RAW disk files on the host.

How do I tell which partition on the guest is using which file on the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each disk shows up as a device in the guest and `lsblk` in the guest. That should give you an overview of which partitions are part of which device.

If you are using virtio, then you can establish which virtio devices are used by which partition by listing them with:

```
ls -l /sys/class/block/{*vda,*vdb,*vdc,*vdd}
```

(on the guest)

So for example, if a df on the guest shows this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           754M  1.5M  752M   1% /run
/dev/vda1       2.0G  1.3G  556M  71% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            203M     0  203M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/vdb1       2.0G  687M  1.2G  37% /var
/dev/vdd1        20G   15G  3.8G  80% /home/mail
/dev/vdc1        20G  9.5G  8.8G  52% /var/mail
```

the block devices will show like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  1 23:58 /sys/class/block/vda -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0a.0/virtio1/block/vda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  1 23:58 /sys/class/block/vdb -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0b.0/virtio2/block/vdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  1 23:58 /sys/class/block/vdc -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0/virtio3/block/vdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  2 00:00 /sys/class/block/vdd -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/virtio4/block/vdd
```

so you can see that /dev/vda1 is using the VM host file identified as "virtio1"

Other disk types (qcow2, vmdk, etc.) should obey a similar process of identifying themselves from the guest to the VM host.

Answer (score 0):

libguestfs has a number of utilities for looking at disk images from the host. In particular [virt-filesystems](http://libguestfs.org/virt-filesystems.1.html)

Comment: Thanks, but  libguestfs-tools is a huge amount of stuff to install, and seeing as I'm unlikely to be needing to know this more than once, I think I'll just try mounting each from a boot disk, noting the contents and then re-naming the files according to the mounts they're used by.

Comment: That works. libguestfs can show you some things read only while the guest is live, and would be safer if you did not trust the guest.